# How to format date and time in JavaScript based on

Tags: javascript, formatting

What is the best and a clean way for me to format date and time string in following format?

```
For today:
HH:MM PM/AM
For any time not today:
MM(short string) DD(short string) HH:MM PM/AM
```

```
const displayTime = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  hour12: true,
});
console.log(displayTime) //=>"May 18, 5:18 PM"

//expected 4:26 PM for today
//expected MAY 1ST(2ND, 3RD, 4TH) 4:26 PM for any day not today
```

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track with `toLocaleDateString`, but it can't do one format for today and one for older on it's own - you'll have to roll that yourself as there is some implicit logic - do you mean this day or in the last 24 hours? Do you handle timezones? How should future times be handled? And so on.

Assuming you mean *today* this would be:

```
const d = dateIWantToFormat;

// Is this date today?
const today = d.toDateString() === new Date().toDateString();

const displayTime = d.toLocaleDateString(
    'en-US', 
    today ? {            // If today just show "HH:MM PM/AM"
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      hour12: true,
    } : 
    {                    // Otherwise show "mmm DD HH:MM PM/AM"
      month: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      hour12: true,
    });
```

Comment: we can assume no future time occurs from date input `dateIWantToFormat` in your case  and `dateIWantToFormat` should be utc time so if `dateIWantToFormat` has the same date as localdate then only display time

Comment: based on your answer it is possible to format like `MAY 1ST(2ND, 3RD, 4TH) 4:26 PM `?

Comment: @jacobcan118 Then this script should give you the right formatting - do you need it in uppercase?